# Meta return error code 1357010 when do business authentication

Tags: facebook

We have registered multiple apps Meta for developer.
Now, we're trying to set up business authentication.
But, in all apps, console displays error and following url returns an error response(error code:1357010).
https://developers.facebook.com/business/application/?app_id=***&business_id=***

Could you please tell me what this error code means?

In addition, our facebook account is now restricting by Meta.
I think this is the cause of the error in business authentication.

thanks!